# VBA, error in the IF logic, how to exit out of it

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following worksheets

Raw > Title > Project 1 > Project 2 > Closing

The code skips worksheets "Raw" and "Title" just fine with "if ws is not".
It runs on "Project 1" and "Project 2" just fine but somehow the "inner for loop and inner if" runs on "Closing" too.

The vlookup part in the inner loop runs on "Closing" which I aim not to.
I want the inner code to just run on "Project 1" and "Project 2".

Please help.

Code:

```
' some variable declations above...
' some variable declations above...

Set ws_raw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw")
Set ws_title = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Title")
Set ws_closing = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Closing")

With ws_raw
    int_last_row_of_raw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    int_last_col_of_raw = 4
    Set rng_raw = .Range("A2", .Cells(int_last_row_of_raw, int_last_col_of_raw))
End With

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws Is ws_raw _
    Or Not ws Is ws_title _
    Or Not ws Is ws_closing Then

        project_name = ws.Range("B1").Value
        int_last_row_of_ws = 13

        For int_current_row_of_ws = 4 To int_last_row_of_ws
            cell_value = ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 1).Value
            If cell_value = "Concept Stage" Or cell_value = "Development Stage" Or cell_value = "Implementation Stage" Then
                stage_name = cell_value

                With rng_raw
                    .AutoFilter 1, project_name
                    .AutoFilter 2, stage_name
                End With

                Set rng_filtered_raw = ws_raw.Range("C3", ws_raw.Cells(int_last_row_of_raw, int_last_col_of_raw)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Else
                If Not rng_filtered_raw Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox (project_name & ": " & cell_value)
                    ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell_value, rng_filtered_raw, 2, False)
                End If
            End If
        Next int_current_row_of_ws
    End If
Next ws

MsgBox ("before first autofilter toggle")
rng_raw.AutoFilter      ' Toggle off AutoFilter

MsgBox ("before second autofilter toggle")
rng_raw.AutoFilter      ' Toggle on AutoFilter with no criteria
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `OR` logic. `AND` logic makes more sense here when you try to say it must be neither of them.

Without looking at the rest of your code you got two options as I see it:

- If you are not going to expand on your sheets and you only need to run the inner `For` loop on "Project 1" and "Project 2", simply change to:

  ```
  If ws.Name = "Project 1" Or ws.Name = "Project 2" Then
  ```
- If you planning on keep going this way with excluded worksheets, just change `OR` to `AND` logic:

  ```
  If Not ws Is ws_raw _
  And Not ws Is ws_title_page _ 'Notice you made a typo here!
  And Not ws Is ws_closing Then
  ```

---

**EDIT**

**1)** Why does `OR` logic not work in your case:

Let's keep this extremely basic: If you have an apple, and you are checking if this is:

- **not** the same as a pear (this return `True`)
- **or not** the same as a banana (this return `True`)
- **or not** the same as an apple (this return `False`, it's the exact same thing)

Now, what `OR` logic does is: "Is there **any** `True` returned out of these three comparisons?" If the answer is yes, then continue with the *inner* code.

---

**2)** Why does `AND` logic work in your case:

Let's keep this extremely basic: If you have an apple, and you are checking if this is:

- **not** the same as a pear (this return `True`)
- **and not** the same as a banana (this return `True`)
- **and not** the same as an apple (this return `False`, it's the exact same thing)

Now, what `AND` logic does is: "Are **all** three comparisons returning `True`?" If the answer is yes, then continue with the *inner* code.

---

Comment: Well, I have like more than 50 project worksheets in real life, so *** If ws.Name = "Project 1" Or ws.Name = "Project 2" Then *** is a no go.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that I should be using AND instead of OR. My code works now. I would like to make sense of why OR is not applicable for my outermost IF so may I ask for more guidance? I am new to programming.

Comment: I basically want to know why the OR caused the code to run on "Closing".

Comment: @XYZKLM, I edited the answer. Note, not only did `ws_closing` ran your inner codes, so did the other sheets! You might just not have noticed it due to other factors within your inner code itself. Now, if this has answered your question, please accept it as such by clicking the checkmark to its left.

Comment: thank you very much. I have learned a lot from you. It is still confusing (atleast for my code) but I will force myself to wrap my head around the overall concept (again, atleast for my code). The apple analogy is very helpful though.

Comment: @XYZKLM, no worries. Something that might be helpfull is to run your code step by step using F8 and see what happens and when it does so. You can check values of variables by hovering over them with the cursor. A simple way to understand this logic. Glad it helped

Comment: I guess the outermost FOR loop kind of threw me off with the IF using ORs....

Comment: AND:
If it's not an apple, and not a banana, and not a pear then eat it (run code).

Comment: OR:
If it's not an apple but it could be a banana or a pear or something else then eat it (run code) ///   
If it's not a banana but it could be an apple or a pear or someting else then eat it (run code) ///   
If it's not a pear but it could be an apple or a banana or something else then eat it (run code)

Comment: JvdV, thanks for this tip:  Something that might be helpfull is to run your code step by step using F8, will defnitely try it... Take care..